# Как создать объект имеющий атрибут с коллекцией этого же объекта?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Создаю объект `node` имеющий атрибут с типом данных коллекция `node`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE node force AS OBJECT (
    sValue VARCHAR2(10)
    ,aChild  nodes)
/    
CREATE OR REPLACE  TYPE nodes IS TABLE OF ref node
/ 

declare
  p node := node (aChild => nodes(), sValue => '1');
  c node := node (aChild => nodes(), sValue => '2');
begin
  p.aChild.Extend;
  p.aChild(p.aChild.Last) := ref (c);
end;
```

Получаю ошибку:

> ORA-06550: line 6, column 30:
> PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'REF'
> ORA-06550: line 6, column 3:
> PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Как исправить данную ошибку, или есть другие способы создать похожую структуру?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тип данных `REF` это условная ссылка на сущность пользовательского типа данных сохранённой в объектной таблице. В PL/SQL его нельзя использовать для создания ссылки на переменную.

Типы данных в вопросе имеют циклическую зависимость. В сообщении об ошибке в этом случае,  упомянается о `REF`, но в PL/SQL контексте это не будет решением.

Попробуйте так:

```
create or replace type node force as object (value varchar2 (10)) not final
/
create or replace type nodes force is table of node
/
create or replace type pnode force under node (child nodes);
/
```

Воспроизводимый пример, как эти типы данных можно использовать:

```
var rc refcursor;
declare
    r pnode := pnode (Child => nodes(), Value => '1');
    n pnode := pnode (Child => nodes(), Value => '2');
begin null;
    
    n.Child.Extend (2);
    n.Child (1) := node (Value => '3');
    n.Child (2) := node (Value => '4');
    r.Child.Extend;
    r.Child (1) := n;
    
    open :rc for 
        select r.value root, p.value parent, c.value leaf 
        from table (r.child) p, treat (value (p) as pnode).child c;
end;
/
```

Даст такой результат:

```
ROOT       PARENT     LEAF      
---------- ---------- ----------
1          2          3         
1          2          4
```